# How to calculate yesterday records with today records using progress 4gl?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have written a program and i need to calculate yesterday records(timing 12:00 AM to 05:00 AM) with today records

```
for each womf_worder of sfcf_au_ship where 
         womf_worder.word_production_status EQ "B"                      and 
         womf_worder.word_build_date        EQ today - 1                and 
         womf_worder.word_build_time        GE tt_shift.shft_start_hour and
         womf_worder.word_build_time        LE tt_shift.shft_stop_hour  
         no-lock: 

    assign i = i + 1.
end.
```

But the problem is I need to calculate the orders only on those mentioned time(12:00 AM to 05:00 AM) with today records. Could you please help this case?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't really understand what you want to do.
Your code examples counts the records created(?) yesterday in a certain time interval.
What exactly do you mean by "calculate ... with today records"?

Comment: yes i want to count yesterday records with today records i.e count yesterday  records with today records up to 05:00 AM only

Comment: it may help if you provide a sample of input data and the expected output

Comment: I agree with Stefan, that might make it easier to understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know your data doesn't have 'future' dates in it, you could use something like this:

```
for each womf_worder of sfcf_au_ship where 
         womf_worder.word_production_status EQ "B"                      and 
         womf_worder.word_build_date        GE today - 1                and 
         womf_worder.word_build_time        GE tt_shift.shft_start_hour and
         womf_worder.word_build_time        LE tt_shift.shft_stop_hour  
         no-lock: 

  assign i = i + 1.
end.
```

If you are not familiar with the data you are working with or want it to be more portable:

```
for each womf_worder of sfcf_au_ship where 
         womf_worder.word_production_status EQ "B"                      and 
         womf_worder.word_build_time        GE tt_shift.shft_start_hour and
         womf_worder.word_build_time        LE tt_shift.shft_stop_hour  and
         ( womf_worder.word_build_date      eq today - 1                or
           womf_worder.word_build_date      eq today                       )
         no-lock: 

  assign i = i + 1.
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand it looks you need to use brackets and an "OR" operator,
so you'll need something like this:

```
FOR EACH  womf_worder OF sfcf_au_ship no-lock
   WHERE  womf_worder.word_production_status EQ "B"                      
     AND (womf_worder.word_build_date        EQ today - 1                
     AND  womf_worder.word_build_time        GE tt_shift.shft_start_hour)
      OR (womf_worder.word_build_date        EQ today 
     AND  womf_worder.word_build_time        LE tt_shift.shft_stop_hour)
          : 
   ASSIGN i = i + 1.
END.
```

Hope this helps.